Unable to find sqlservr-setup file
I used these following commands:

sudo dnf config-manager --add-repo=https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/9/mssql-server-2022.repo

sudo dnf config-manager --add-repo=https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/9/prod.repo

sudo dnf check-update

sudo dnf -y install mssql-server mssql-tools


When I went to go check for the sqlservr-setup file in
/opt/mssql/bin/ it wasn't there. Where can I find that file on line?

Did you follow the install instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-red-hat?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=rhel9 ?  That says you should run sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup

No I haven't thank you. Using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456061/configuring-mssql-server-on-ubuntu-cannot-open-or-read-the-persistent-registry also helped.
